# How to publish message from WSO2 ESB to RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, wso2-esb

I am trying to configure wso2 esb with rabbitmq. I've read this [article](http://kishanthan.wordpress.com/2013/03/26/amqp-transport-for-wso2-esb-based-on-rabbitmq-java-client/).Whenever i  sent a message from the sender , It reached out the queue named Q1 as well as ESB console. But it doesn't reach queue named Q2.
Does anybody has a solution ?

thanks

Comment: If it doesn't reach Q2 then the problem is in out flow. Make sure you added the correct `transportSender` in axis2.xml file and have the correct endpoint address in your proxy service.

Comment: i have given <transportSender name="rabbitmq"
class="org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSender"/> as my transport sender and   <endpoint>
         <address uri="rabbitmq:/AMQPProxy?rabbitmq.server.host.name=192.168.1.74&rabbitmq.server.port=5672&rabbitmq.server.user.name=guest&rabbitmq.server.password=guest&rabbitmq.queue.name=test&rabbitmq.exchange.name=test"/>
      </endpoint> as my end point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the provided end-point all messages should publish to the queue test via test exchange. You can introduce rabbitmq.queue.routing.key property to your endpoint and bind your test queue to test exchange using that route key.

If you have already configured axis2.xml/proxy service correctly according to the documentation[1], there can be a configuration issue at your RabbitMQ server side.You can confirm that writing a simple java client according to the article[2] or refer this tutorial[2].

Or you may remove test-queue/test-exchange from RabbitMQ server and try your endpoint.

[1]. http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB460/RabbitMQ+AMQP+Transport
[2]. http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html